# Metallb Kubernetes Loadbalancer fails without the port

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, metallb

I'm using Metallb for a bare-metal kubernetes cluster.

I've modified the configmap as below,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    #- name: default
      #protocol: layer2
      #addresses:
      #- 192.168.1.240-192.168.1.250
    - addresses:
      - <Public_IP_01>/32
      - <Public_IP_02>/32
      - <Public_IP_03>/32
      name: prod
      protocol: layer2
```

And however the right ip is assigned, it's not reachable at http://<Public_IP_01>, but it's reachable through http://<Public_IP_01>:31158. I feel like it's working as nodeport not the load balancer

```
k get svc -A
default       nginx-service   LoadBalancer   10.98.4.122      <Public_IP_01>     80:31158/TCP             7m3s
```

Any ideas how to enforce traffic on port 80.

Thanks,

Comment: It's minikube or kubeadm? How did you deploy `MetalLB`, Helm or YAML Manifests? Could you provide outputs of `kubectl describe service <service name> -n <namespace>` and `kubectl -n <namespace> get endpoints <service>`

Comment: `k describe service odoo-srv -n odoo`
`Name:              odoo-srv`
`Namespace:         odoo`
`Labels:            name=odoo`
`Annotations:       metallb.universe.tf/address-pool: prod`
`Selector:          app=odoo,tier=frontend`
`Type:              ClusterIP`
`IP:                10.111.164.114`
`Port:              <unset>  80/TCP`
`TargetPort:        8069/TCP`
`Endpoints:         10.244.1.193:8069`
`Session Affinity:  None`
`Events:            <none>`

Comment: `k -n odoo get endpoints odoo-srv
NAME       ENDPOINTS           AGE
odoo-srv   10.244.1.193:8069   11m`

Comment: `NAMESPACE       NAME                                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE`
`ingress-nginx   service/ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.101.224.193   <none>        80:32196/TCP,443:31575/TCP   44d`
`ingress-nginx   service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.98.201.38     <none>        443/TCP                      44d`
`odoo            service/odoo-srv                             ClusterIP   10.111.164.114   <none>        80/TCP                       8m39s`

Comment: sorry about the format